# How to run a script inside a modal that is loaded from another page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I am loading my modal from another page:

```
("#EditModalBodyDiv").load(url, function () {
                        $("#EditModal").modal("show");
});
```

i want to run the following script inside the modal where i will be setting a text in a select box, this text is a variable coming from the server, but because the modal has not loaded yet, the variable (@ViewBag.defactionPlatformName) is not set:

```
<script>
    $("#aEditPlatformName option:selected").text(@ViewBag.defactionPlatformName);
</script>
```

Comment: Is your modal a partial view? Is this script in the calling view or in the partial view? Why do you use the partial view like that, why don't you render it directly?

Comment: make modal content as a partial view and write the above script in `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Thanks, the partial view idea worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to replace the script, to emit it, with an arbitrary html element let's call it `receivedscript` while loading, using:

```
$("#EditModal").replace(/(<\/?)script([^>]*>)/img,'$1receivedscript style="display:none!important;"$2');
```

and after loading the modal, you have to execute the emitted scripts:

```
$("#EditModal").find('receivedscript:not([src])').each(function(){
   try {
      eval(this.innerHTML);
   } catch (e) {}
});
```